# Using index in an array to make a sum

Tags: cplex, opl

I've been thrown into a Cplex and have absolutly no experience using it. I might be missing some obvious information.

We are trying to build a simple optimization model on a port's train processing capacity. Every product treated has its own path using several railway segments. I am looking for a way to get my current index in my segment array to make a sum.

In short, i am looking for the equivalent of a ".getindex()" in Cplex. I have looked around to no avail.

Here is a simplified version of the relevant parameters.

```
int amountSegments=6;
int products=1..2;
int time=15;
int path[products][segments]=[[2,1,4,5],[2,1,3,6,4,5]];
```

Here is one of the relevant constraints

```
forall(l in products)
   forall(i in path)
     sum(t in XXXX)
     x[i][l][t]==d[l];
```

What i am trying to do here, if x is the amount of wagon on each [segment] containing [product] at [time]: for each of the two products and for every segments in that products path, i want to sum t in i.getindex() .. time-amountSegments+i.getindex().

Thank you in advance, i hope this is somewhat understandable.

Edit: I will try to clear my question up. 
We have two products, 1 and 2. Product one path consist of paths : 2,1,4,5 and product two consist of paths 2,1,3,6,4,5. For that specific constraint, for product one, the model needs to generate a sum for segments 2, 1, 4 and 5. The order is important for the rest of the model.

For segment 2, i need the sum on t from 1 to 12 (first segment on path so 15-4+1)

For segment 1, i need the sum on t from 2 to 13 (second segment on path so 15-4+2)

for segment 4, i need the sum on t from 3 to 14 (third segment on path so 15-4+3)

For segment 5, i need the sum on t from 4 to 15 (fourth segment on path so 15-4+4)

For the second product:
For segment 2, i need the sum on t from 1 to 10 (first segment on path so 15-6+1)

For segment 1, i need the sum on t from 2 to 11 (second segment on path so 15-6+2)

For segment 3, i need the sum on t from 2 to 12 (third segment on path so 15-6+3)

for segment 6, i need the sum on t from 3 to 13 (fourth segment on path so 15-6+4)

For segment 4, i need the sum on t from 4 to 14 (fifth segment on path so 15-6+5)

For segment 5, i need the sum on t from 2 to 15 (sixth segment on path so 15-6+6)

In short, for [i], i need the model to read the path array for the right product. 
For [l], it's pretty straight forward I think.
For sum on [t], I need to go from my position in the path array(index+1) to (total time-amount of segments in the path+position in the path array)

I hope this explains my problem a little better!

Comment: It's not clear to me what `i` is when you refer to `i.getindex()`.  It may be easier to understand your question if you would explain how you defined `x`, as it seems you mixed up the first two dimensions for `x`.

Comment: I defined X as x[segment][product][time].
for product one i would like to do the sum of : x[2][1][from 1 to (15-4+1)] as this is the first segment in the array. x[1][1][from 2 to 15-4+2)] as this is the second segment in the array. So on and so forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the number of segments is different for each product, I think you have to use tuples

```
dvar boolean x[1..10];

int time=0;
range products=1..2;
{int} paths[products]=[ {2,1,4,5},
                        {2,1,3,6,4,5} ];

minimize (0);

subject to {
forall(p in products)
   sum(t in paths[p]) x[time+t]==0;
}
```

`p` will vary from 1 to 2. For `p == 1`, `t` will iterate over `paths[1]` which is the tuple `{2, 1, 4, 5}`. And you can add any constant `time` to `t` when indexing `x`... So you will get the sum of `x[2]`, `x[1]`, `x[4]`, `x[5]`, as here `t == 0`.

The trick is that the tuples that are in the array `paths` don't need to have all the same size.  While a matrix, as in your question, must be regular: you can't have one row with 4 elements, and another with 6.

Comment: Editted my question, as i think it wasn't clear as I feared. Thanks for your the time you are taking.

Comment: I changed my answer.

Comment: Thanks, Your comments helped me understand a part of the problems I was getting. I still have a few questions, but I will make another post as they might not be directly related.